# jQuery AJAX POST skips Django CSRF token header on first call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, csrf

### Using jQuery AJAX POST to call Django for an updated JSON set.

Have included both 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' and 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware' for the Django app and the code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax in my JS file.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    function safeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

**What happens**

1. Clear browser cookies and load the page.
2. Django responds to the AJAX POST request with 403 forbidden, *and then* sets a cookie with the CSRF.  But there is no JSON data.
3. Trigger the AJAX POST request again
4. Django receives the CSRF token from the X-CSRFToken header and responds appropriately with the JSON set.

The html and js files that are producing the ajax requests are NOT django produced.  The js is interacting with django through jquery $.post() .  So the only way to get a csrf token is to make a call to django before sending the post data.

It seems to me that the jQuery function solution given in the Django docs doesn't have a local cookie yet and is not waiting to get the cookie back from the server before it submits the POST request.  But when it gets one along with the 403, it uses the (now locally stored) cookie for subsequent tries and works fine.

How can this be fixed so the cookie is set ahead of time and used by the AJAX POST request the first time around?  Am I wrong to believe that django csrf can be made to work strictly from ajax calls originating on the same site?

---

*Other questions here relating to CSRF not working at all have suggested using ajax.Setup instead of ajaxSend, but according to this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15284?cversion=0&cnum_hist=6 , that could cause problems with other JS, so ajaxSend was chosen.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like middleware classes was placed in wrong order. To get right answer need more information,provide MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES from settings.py.

> Add the middleware 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to your
>   list of middleware classes, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. (**It should come and
>   before any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been
>   dealt with.**)
>
> Alternatively, you can use the decorator csrf_protect() on particular
>   views you want to protect (see below).

Source: [How to use CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',  
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    )

Comment: The csrf middleware seems to be working ok from the django perspective since the first ajax request gets a token from django and the second request uses the token and django is happy.

Comment: Actually CSRF cookie must be set at first step, when page was loaded

Comment: The page with the AJAX in it was not built in Django.  It is straight HTML (though I am rebuilding it in Django to deal with this problem and others) Though as I understand it, that shouldn't matter.  The AJAX call should be able to get and read a cookie provided by Django without any full page request.  It just seems that the script isn't getting the cookie from the remote before sending the post data.  It's only looking for a local cookie which isn't there yet on the first request.  It seems that what is needed is to make the CSRF value required before sending POST data to Django

Comment: That makes sense, because Django provides security exactly from that kind of requests. The cookie is have to be set when Django returns response with page that uses ajax calls. Though you can use [@csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) to disable csrf check on views that handle AJAX, or implement that straight HTML page into view.

Comment: My understanding is that Django provides security to prevent "Cross Site Request Forgery".  My html and js files are on the same site and don't need to be protected against.  The use case here is when Django needs to interact with another application on the same server through AJAX calls.  I might be using Wordpress for example and want to have custom dynamic content displayed on a side bar.  Wordpress PHP can't get the csrf token from django directly or ask django for a cookie.  But the docs indicate AJAX requests should work.  And it mostly does, with a flaw.